# Scrollbar not Showing up for Javascript SimpleScrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

A scrollbar should appear for div and textarea for iPadOS. The color of the scrollbar should be black.

```css
.ss-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
}

.ss-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + 18px);
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ss-content.rtl {
  width: calc(100% + 18px);
  right: auto;
}

.ss-scroll {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 9px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
}

.ss-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.ss-container:hover .ss-scroll,
.ss-container:active .ss-scroll {
  opacity: 1;
}

.ss-grabbed {
  -o-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-scrollbar@latest/simple-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="simple-scrollbar.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="ss-container">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</div>
<p>Textarea</p>
<textarea class="ss-container" style="overflow-y: scroll; border-radius: 25px;" rows="30" cols="10">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

[This](https://github.com/buzinas/simple-scrollbar) is the documentation.

Comment: why `class="ss-container"`? documentation says you must specify `ss-container` as an attribute, not as a class, like this: `<div ss-container>...</div>`

Comment: why are you explicitly setting `overflow-y: scroll`? SimpleScrollbar takes care of that, you don't have to apply that style.

Comment: I tested the library, it doesn't work with `<textarea>` elements.

Comment: Ok. Can you help me get it to work for div please?

Comment: in your code snippet, you linked SimpleScrollbar javascript file, but you didn't link the CSS file.

Comment: here is a modified version of your fiddle, showing how this can be applied to a `div`: https://jsfiddle.net/qhzb32or/

Comment: in the end, I'm pretty sure it was not a problem related to iOS.

Comment: Haha. I need to make sure the scrollbar is black and that it doesn't overlap the text. Any way those things are possible?

Comment: sure, you can colorize the scrollbar like this in CSS: `.ss-scroll { background: black !important; }` and just add some `padding` to the `<p>` element to avoid text overlap: https://jsfiddle.net/qhzb32or/1/

Comment: The scrollbar is still obstructing the text.

Comment: still? give it more padding to the right, as in: `<p style="padding: 5px 25px 5px 5px;">`

Comment: Ok how do I make the scrollbar always visible? I can't find the right css property.

Comment: I made the scrollbar always visible. Only problem is when you swipe down the scrollbar goes out of bounds from the box. Please help me fix this problem.

Comment: updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d73zjgc4/ - solved via CSS adding `opacity: 1 !important` to `.ss-scroll`

Comment: The scroller still goes out of the box when you scroll down. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Set div to 150px height to see what I mean please.

Comment: I don't see any problems: https://jsfiddle.net/aq0vc8j7/

Comment: The scroller goes out of the box a bit on iPad when I scroll to the bottom.